# Type error: unhashable type: 'list' (using sets)

Tags: python

I just want to set the words from two texts together in a set, to get all the unique words. When I run this code I get a Type Error: unhashable type: 'list'

What can I do differently?

```
infile1 = open("random.txt", 'r')
infile2 = open("random_encr.txt", 'r')

data1 = infile1.read()
data2 = infile2.read()

#close files
infile1.close()
infile2.close()

# replace all dots with empty string
data1 = data1.replace('.', '')
data2 = data2.replace('.', '')

# split words in data (splitted by whitespace) and save in words
words1 = data1.split()
words2 = data2.split()

set1 = set([words1])
set2 = set([words2])

set1.update(set2)

print(set1)
```

Comment: On which line you have this error?

Comment: ah, you seem to be initializing set with list of lists. words1 is a list and [words1] is something like [['word1', 'word2', ...]]. Can you try `set1 = set(words1)` instead?

Comment: Yeah, your probably right. The errors is at line 19, where I create the sets

Comment: One thing you can do differently is make a function that returns the set of words given a filename.  Almost half your code is duplicated stuff as it is.

Comment: If you are doing heavy work with text I'll recommend you use NLTK. Is a python package for text processing and has functionalities like "tokenize" a text.

Comment: I will definitely look into that, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is an error in the argument your passing to `set`:

`set1 = set([words1])` is defining a list of one item - that contains a list of words.

- eg: `[["a", "b", "c"]]` ...
- when I guess you would want only `["a", "b", "c"]`.

remove the `[]` and do `set1 = set(words1)`

Comment: Yeah, as kedder also mentioned in the comments, this was my problem. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to generate a list of all words that appear in either document:

```
infile1 = open("1.txt", 'r')
infile2 = open("2.txt", 'r')

data1 = infile1.read()
data2 = infile2.read()

#close files
infile1.close()
infile2.close()

# replace all dots with empty string
data1 = data1.replace('.', '')
data2 = data2.replace('.', '')

# split words in data (splitted by whitespace) and save in words
words1 = data1.split()
words2 = data2.split()

#create combined list
combinedList = []

for word in words1:
    if word not in combinedList:
        combinedList.append(word)

for word in words2:
    if word not in combinedList:
        combinedList.append(word)

print(combinedList)
```

Comment: sorry, this comment is out of place here, but I don't know how remove it. If you are doing heavy work with text I'll recommend you use NLTK. Is a python package for text processing and has functionalities like "tokenize" a text.

Comment: No doubt (I use the nltk all the time)! I just wanted to show the user how to modify their code slightly to get the functionality they want.

Comment: Yes, I see my bad, my comment was for Ragner, not for you. :D